# Why my animation doesn't repeat?

Tags: android, animation

I've got `repeatCount` set as **INFINITE** (-1) and repeatMode set as **RESTART** (1)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE

Even though my animation works, it doesn't repeat properly. What's missing in my code?

```
public class SyncActivity extends Activity {

    Animation slideanim;
    ImageView senoide;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);

        senoide = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        slideanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);
        //slideanim.setFillAfter(true);
        slideanim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        slideanim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);

        senoide.setAnimation(slideanim);
        senoide.startAnimation(slideanim);
    }
}
```

move.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-18.5%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Why `setFillAfter(true)` if your animation doesn't finish?

Comment: Yeah it's a little bit odd, but I had it commented on my code before posting here. My bad.

Comment: Don't use setAnimation. `If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation) instead`

Comment: I don't want to run it immediately. There will be more code between setting and starting it. Thus, it makes no difference since the animation doesn't repeat.

Comment: I was just saying that because you call `startAnimation` right after you call `setAnimation`. Please post your `R.anim.move` so we can be of more assistance.

Comment: I know, thank's for your help. Check the updated code.

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your xml? `android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"`

Comment: That did the job. I always avoid setting things in the XML cause I rather do it programatically. Please post as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your XML to have the repeat mode and count on it:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-18.5%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:repeatCount="infinite"
             android:repeatMode="restart"
             android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: is there any actual reason for that? why wouldn't the setter do the same thing?

Comment: Maybe the XML overrides the setter. I'm also confused and trying to look for some explanation on the documentation

Comment: Oh.. I think it's because of the `<set` tag.